# Sensation of something tingling on head-hair - not itchy

Tags: hair, parasites, head-lice

I occasionally have this sensation that feels like something is crawling on a specific place on my head hair (left side about 2" above ear). It comes and goes, no certain time or periods to forecast when it will take place or leave.
 It's also very subtle, so I can sense it when I'm relaxed in a quite environment.
I have been experiencing this for months.

It's not itching or hurting, just a bit of tingling. Merely feels that something is doing its business in there. But it's always in the exact location.

Can my scalp be inhabited by parasites or lice? How can I really inspect what is going on in there?

Comment: @JohnP, I've updated the title, is this any better?

Comment: No. Your question is solely "why is my head itching?". It was edited once to remove the personal elements and make it generic enough that it could stay open, you rolled back those edits. We don't diagnose personal medical questions. See a doctor.

Comment: @JohnP, 1) The question was stating clearly that head isn't itching = no lice. 2) This has been too much of a hassle. Can you please just delete the question then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [NHS recommends **not to use** any of the following treatment options](https://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/Head-lice/Pages/Treatment.aspx):

- products containing permethrin
- head lice "repellents"
- electric head lice combs
- **tree and plant oil treatments, such as tea tree oil, eucalyptus oil, and lavender oil**
- **herbal remedies**

### [The very basic option](https://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/Head-lice/Pages/Treatment.aspx):

> Wet combing involves removing head lice with a special fine-toothed
> comb. It's suitable for everyone and is relatively inexpensive. A
> number of lice removal combs are available to buy. Combs with
> flat-faced teeth spaced 0.2-0.3mm apart are best for removing head
> lice, although combs with smaller gaps can be used to remove eggs and
> nits (egg cases) after treatment. The comb may come with instructions
> outlining how to use it.
> A commonly used method is described in the linked article.

### [The simple option](https://www.webmd.com/children/tc/lice-topic-overview):

Because Wet-Combing can fail (lice cling to the hair and scalp of the host): you could buy an over-the-counter Lotion that is supposed to kill lice, follow the instruction and comb your hair with a specially designed comb for lice (you can usually find that at your local drug store). If no lice are brushed out, you don’t have lice. This will kill other parasites as well.

[National Geographic Image](http://kids.nationalgeographic.com/content/dam/kids/photos/animals/Bugs/H-P/head-louse-from-above.jpg) for reference (Note that lice are very small and appear like small black dots to the naked eye, if you are unsure, use a magnifying glass):
[image]

### Visit a doctor

**If this doesn’t solve your issue and the itching preservers**, visit a General Practitioner. [WebMD has further recommendations who to see when.](https://www.webmd.com/children/tc/lice-when-to-call-a-doctor)

---

For more information on lice lotions, visit the [CDC and go to section Over-the-Counter.](https://www.cdc.gov/parasites/lice/head/treatment.html)

Comment: Some lice medications are very strong, some fairly toxic so I wouldn't use them unless you had to. Best to ask a doctor first. And lice are now becoming resistant to lice medications.

Comment: @padma Thanks for pointing that out, I’ve edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lice comb and look for nits as well. My family and I had them once after traveling and we used olive oil and a lice comb and it worked well.